# Javascript increment operator

Tags: javascript

```
totalvalue = 0;
for (x=1; x<6; x++)
{
totalvalue += document.getElementById("rcv_amount_"+x).value;
}
```

> rcv_amount_1 = 2
>   rcv_amount_2 = 4
>   rcv_amount_3 = 6

expected result is 12, but i am getting 0246.

Any help?

Comment: You're adding strings, convert them to numbers and you'll be fine ;)

Comment: Looks like you're concatenating strings instead of making additions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
totalvalue += parseInt(document.getElementById("rcv_amount_"+x).value, 10);
```

Comment: You should always specify the second argument to parseInt, i.e. `parseInt(..., 10) to ensure the value is treated as a decimal number (and not e.g. octal or hex)

Comment: As far as I know, that parameters is optional, and 10 by default.

Comment: No, by default it's guessed from the string. And while octal (leading zero) is gone in most browsers, it still handles `0x...` as hex

Comment: Couln't agree more. Always use JSLint to prevent such situations. They can be a pain to find.

Comment: @Portnoy it's optional, but the default value is _zero_, meaning "figure it out from the string".

Answer (score 6):

You have to convert the `.value` into a number - initially the `.value` property of an `<input>` element is a *string*, so the `+=` operator results in concatenation, not addition.

To convert a string value into a number you can use `parseInt(..., 10)` for integers, or `parseFloat(...)` or just `+(...)` for non-integers.